# How to turn off Safari's prefetch feature?

Tags: safari, prefetch

Safari has a "feature" which preloads pages while you are typing in the url.

Now for most users this is indeed a feature, speeding up page loads. But for web developers it can cause trouble - especially when it automatically loads scripts (such as importers or background scripts) that you have used earlier but have no intention of running currently.

This happens under Safari 8.x but it is possible that this was also the case on older versions.

Also, note that this feature is distinct from "DNS prefetch" which is the only related explanation I have come across - I have disabled DNS prefetch and that did not solve this issue...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is much simpler than I thought. :)

[image]

Comment: this is not really an answer from a web developer's perspective, as you can't be asking users to diable browser functionality. Many browsers send a specific header (eg. 'Purpose: Prefetch' in chrome) that allows the server side to filter requests (eg. return a 503) but Safari doesn't send any distinguishing header field. It also seems to try to prefetch POST requests, which seems very broken to me.

Comment: `Purpose: Prefetch` is very helpful indeed!

But my question was relating to my own use of Safari as a developer, unintentionally triggering requests. Though you have a valid point, the user may also do this unintentionally (though I suppose this is less common)...