# CodeIgniter sends three mails instead of one

Tags: codeigniter, newsletter, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter 3.02 for sending a newsletter. I'm just sending 1 mail to one recipient, but I receive the same mail 3 times.

I don't use a loop. I don't understand why three mails were sent.

My code :

```
function sendMailProspects(){
    date_default_timezone_set ("Europe/Berlin");

    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['protocol'] = 'mail';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->to('recipient@domaine.com');
    $this->email->from('mymail@mydomaine.com','John DOE');
    $this->email->reply_to('mymail@mydomaine.com', 'John DOE');
    $this->email->subject('Mysubject');
    $this->email->message('<h1>HTML CODE</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident.</p>');
    $this->email->set_alt_message('texte');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

I just execute this method directly in the url, no loop, nothing special.

I've tested this code on localhost and on an shared hosting with the same result: I receive three mails.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry my english is bad, foreach or for ! loop is better. Sorry

Comment: I don't see anything in `sendMailProspects()` method that would cause multiples. Maybe we need to see the code that calls `sendMailProspects()`

Comment: Hi, there is no code to call this method as I said, I execute it directly in the url. May be it's a problème with Codeigniter, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you using Safari with preloading turned on? [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214246/how-to-turn-off-safaris-prefetch-feature). That may explain why the code runs more often than you think, resulting in more mails than you expected.

Comment: No, Firefox 41.0.2, the latest version

Comment: But maybe it's the good way, because I try the same process with Chrome, and the first time I recepted just one email, but after more test, I recepted as new 3 emails

Comment: Do you recieve sent mail imediatelly, or is there some lag?

Comment: I recept  the emails imediately

Comment: `Likely cause`: This may be due to a failure of confirmation that the email was already delivered, somewhere in the email delivery process.

Comment: Sometimes antivirus software on your computer or local network can trigger your email software to behave as if it has not sent a message, when it already has. This is especially true of Outlook.

Comment: Iit's ok, I resolve the problem by a redirection after the call to the function `function index ()
 {
  self::sendMailProspects();
  redirect('newsletter');
 }`